# Toggle next div jquery not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to show/hide a div using JQuery. I have several of these on one page. I'm trying to write something that will trigger when any link with class "toggle" is clicked. It will then look for the next div, relative to the clicked link, with `class="showHide"` and then show it or hide it depending on it's current status.

The trouble I'm having is with the .next() function. It doesn't seem to be working for me.

JS

```
$(document).on("click", ".toggle", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('.showHide').hide();
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="medium-12 columns">
  <h2>Lists</h2>
  <div class="medium-2 columns">
    <h3>Food type</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="medium-10 columns"><small class="toggle">Show / hide</small></div>
  <div class="medium-12 columns showHide">...</div>
</div>
```

If I do something like `$(this).css("background", "red");`, it works fine. So, I'm pretty sure it's the `.next('.showHide')` that's tripping me up.

I've also tried `.nextAll('.showHide')` with a `.first()` and that didn't work either.

Comment: What is your exact html

Comment: Works **[fine here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/zdkL8dp8/)**!

Comment: Are your `toggle` and `showHide` elements *siblings*? If not, `.next` won't work. In fact, it needs to be the next sibling (hence the function name) ;) It would help if you showed your exact HTML.

Comment: Please see the "[MCVE]" guidelines, regarding the need to show a representative sample of your code.

Comment: I just added the html. Sorry for not doing so earlier.

Comment: Nothing is next or a sibling of the selector. Are you willing to change the markup?

Comment: Got it figured out. Moved the <small> out of its containing div. It's not arranged the way I'd like it but at least it's working now!

Comment: That's not the only solution but if you're good with it please delete the question.

Comment: BTW `<span>` doesn't have a default action so there's no need to preventDefault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) selects the *"immediately following sibling"* of the matched element. Similarly, [`nextAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) selects *"all following siblings"*. In your code, the two elements (`.trigger` and `.showHide`) are not siblings.

In order to use `next()`, I suggest traversing from the `.trigger` element to its parent `.medium-10`, which is a sibling of the associated `.showHide` element.

```js
jQuery('.toggle').on('click', function() {
  jQuery(this).parent('.medium-10').next('.showHide').toggle();
});
```

```css
.showHide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="medium-12 columns">
  <h2>Lists</h2>
  <div class="medium-2 columns">
    <h3>Food type</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="medium-10 columns"><small class="toggle">Show / hide</small></div>
  <div class="medium-12 columns showHide">...</div>
  <div class="medium-10 columns"><small class="toggle">Show / hide</small></div>
  <div class="medium-12 columns showHide">...</div>
  <div class="medium-10 columns"><small class="toggle">Show / hide</small></div>
  <div class="medium-12 columns showHide">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is more or less what I ended up doing.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$(this).siblings('div.showHide').toggle();
```

Comment: According to the OP's code, the `.toggle` element has no siblings.